# When I click the Calculate button, it does not display the calculations in textbox for sales tax and total

Tags: javascript

When I run the code on my chrome browser, clicking the calculate button, it does not put the value in the Total and Sales Tax text box.

Also "Add the Javascript event handler for the click event of the Clear button, This should clear all text boxes and move the cursor to the Subtotal field."

I'm using Html and js file. Using a function expression to calculate and display my calculation, then also use the clear button to clear all text boxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="sales_tax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
      <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
     <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p> 
     <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
     <input type="text" id="subtotal" ><br>

<label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
<input type="text" id="tax_rate" ><br>

<label for="sales_tax">Sales Tax:</label>
<input type="text" id="sales_tax" disabled ><br>

<label for="total">Total:</label>
<input type="text" id="total" disabled ><br>

<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" >
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" ><br>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my js file.

```
var $ = function (id) {
return document.getElementById(id); 
};

var SumSalesTax = function (sub, rate){
var sales_tax = (sub * rate);
sales_tax = sales_tax.toFixed(2);
var total = (sub * rate + sub);
total = total.toFixed(2);
return sales_tax, total;
}

var processEntries = function() {
var sub = parseFloat($("subtotal").value);
var rate = parseFloat($("tax_rate").value); 

    if (sub < 0 && sub > 10000 && rate < 0 && rate > 12) {
alert("Subtotal must be > 0 and < 1000, and Tax Rate must be >0 and < 12. 
")
 } else {
$("sales_tax").value = SumSalesTax(sub, rate);

$("total").value = SumSalesTax(sub, rate); 
}       


};

window.onload = function() {
$("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
$("clear").onclick = sumSalesTax;
};
```

[Sales Tax Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HZ8k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you had a typo when you were doing `$("clear").onclick = sumSalesTax;`, as the variable was named `SumSalesTax` rather than with the lower case. This meant that the code block errored out and therefore didn't actually run. Make sure you make good use of the browser console so you can spot errors like this! The below example should work

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
};

var SumSalesTax = function (sub, rate){
    var sales_tax = (sub * rate);
    sales_tax = sales_tax.toFixed(2);
    var total = (sub * rate + sub);
    total = total.toFixed(2);
    return sales_tax, total;
}

var processEntries = function() {
    var sub = parseFloat($("subtotal").value);
    var rate = parseFloat($("tax_rate").value); 

    if (sub < 0 && sub > 10000 && rate < 0 && rate > 12) {
        alert("Subtotal must be > 0 and < 1000, and Tax Rate must be >0 and < 12.")
    } else {
        $("sales_tax").value = SumSalesTax(sub, rate);
        $("total").value = SumSalesTax(sub, rate); 
    }       
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("calculate").onclick = processEntries;
    $("clear").onclick = SumSalesTax;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sales Tax Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="sales_tax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Sales Tax Calculator</h1>
    <p>Enter Subtotal and Tax Rate and click "Calculate".</p> 
    <label for="subtotal">Subtotal:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" ><br>

    <label for="tax_rate">Tax Rate:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tax_rate" ><br>

    <label for="sales_tax">Sales Tax:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sales_tax" disabled ><br>

    <label for="total">Total:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" disabled ><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" >
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" ><br>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! For your input just started to code javascript... Appreciate it!  Yea I'm using notepad++ I need to upgrade.